# Slack API: Send a message verbatim (escaping asterisks, colons)

Tags: slack-api

I'm using the Slack JS SDK's `chat.postMessage` call to post messages to a Slack channel. I'm forwarded text from another source, and I'd like for that text to be posted verbatim.

But I can't figure out how to get Slack to *not* interpret `*`, `_`, and `:`.

I've tried passing in [`mrkdwn: false`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#arg_mrkdwn) and [`parse: 'full'`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#formatting), but the messages always seem to come out the same:

```
    const slackClient = new slack.WebClient(slackApiToken);
    await slackClient.chat.postMessage({
        channel: targetChannel,
        text: '*hello* _bye_ :smile:',
    });
    await slackClient.chat.postMessage({
        channel: targetChannel,
        text: '*hello* _bye_ :smile:',
        parse: 'full',
    });
    await slackClient.chat.postMessage({
        channel: targetChannel,
        text: '*hello* _bye_ :smile:',
        mkrdwn: false,
    });
```

What I want to see in the Slack app:

> *hello* _bye_ :smile:

What I see in the Slack app (for all three `chat.postMessage` calls):

> **hello** *bye*

Is there a way to get Slack to *not* interpret those characters as being special?

- Note: I do *not* want to use a inline code or code block formatting for my message. I just want it to appear in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `text` parameter, you can use `blocks` parameter  to send your 'plain text'

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#blocks_and_attachments

Example:

```
await slackClient.chat.postMessage({
        channel: targetChannel,
        blocks : [{
                   type: 'section',
                   text: {
                            type: 'plain_text',
                            text: '*This* is a _plain_ text section block. :smile:',
                            emoji: false
                            }
                 }]
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this behaviour is a known bug with `chat.postMessage`. I'd recommend reporting this to feedback@slack.com so that the team can get the bug prioritized.